# Why can't I use the nanosleep() function even when time.h is included?

Tags: c, sleep

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/snake-game-in-c/) that has you making a game in C. It uses windows, I'm on linux, so there's already some compatibility issues(conio.h). I figured it's a good challenge, so I decided to try and "port" it.

Anyways, I'm up to the point where I'm programming the logic of the whole thing. I can't have it refreshing millions of times a second, so I obviously need to have it halt for a bit. They used sleep() but somehow passed a float as an argument. Google says "don't use sleep, use usleep()!" Manpage says "don't use usleep(), use nanosleep()!" k ._.

I made a new file and tried to play with it, and I'm stuck. "Independent declaration is invalid"

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
 {
    struct timespec ts;
    {
       long tv_nsec = 10000000;
    }

     nanosleep(&ts, NULL);

     return 0;
```

Comment: your code is missing a clossing bracket but I bet it isn't in your code. Otherwise, impossible to reproduce your error on my machine, an ubuntu 20

Comment: You have a semi-colon after `ts` and then you aren't using valid syntax for initializing a struct. Try: `struct timespec ts = { .tv_nsec = 10000000L };`

Comment: You currently have an block that declares a variable `tv_nsec`, leaving `ts` uninitialized.

Comment: Please include the exact error message from the compiler (including line numbers) in the question.

Comment: You probably need to define a [feature test macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) at the top of the code (before the `#include <time.h>`) such as `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L` (the values `199506L`, `200112L` or `200809L` should also work).

Comment: If you can't get `nanosleep` to work, `usleep` is fine, and easier to use, since you don't need to set up a `timespec` struct.

Comment: Note that you also have to initialize `tv_sec`, once you fixed your initialization. Otherwise you create UB.

Answer (score 2):

"Independent declaration is invalid" is a new one on me, but your code is definitely flawed.  This ...

```
    struct timespec ts;
    {
       long tv_nsec = 10000000;
    }

     nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
```

... leaves variable `ts` with a wholly indeterminate value at the point of the `nanosleep()` call.  In particular, the `long tv_nsec = 10000000` has nothing to do with variable `ts`.  It declares a separate variable named `tv_nsec` whose scope is limited to the block containing that declaration.

It looks like you wanted to write an initializer for `ts`.  That would look more like this:

```
    struct timespec ts = {
       .tv_nsec = 10000000
    };

    nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
```

You may also include a member initializer for `.tv_sec` (separated from the other with a comma), but that is unnecessary if, as in this case, you want it initialized to zero.  If you provide an initializer that does not explicitly initialize all members, then those not explicitly initialized receive initial value 0 (if arithmetic) or `NULL` (if pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Putting comments together:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const struct timespec req = {
        .tv_sec = 0,
        .tv_nsec = 10000000,
    };

    if (nanosleep(&req, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("...");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

And also define the nsec:

```
ts.tv_nsec= 1000000
```

That will work for me.